# What length do my spokes need to be for DT Swiss hubs and rims?

Tags: wheels, hub

I'd like two build a couple of wheels based on DT Swiss hubs.

https://www.bike24.com/p2380232.html ( H24PNCDBR28SA3232S )

https://www.bike24.com/p2380225.html ( H24PACIXR28SA3228S )

Using XR 331 27.5 rims

An I'm trying to order spokes for them using DT Swiss calculator https://spokes-calculator.dtswiss.com/en/calculator

But DT Swiss website and documentation is garbage. I cannot understand what these hubs really are. Are these 240 DBCL straighpull? Or are they 240 EXP2020+? And what does DBCL even stand for?

Would appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 3):

They are straight pull and Disc Brake Centre Lock. You can take measurements when you have the hubs if you are uncertain.